# Google Chrome print preview defaulting to black and white

Tags: google-chrome, printing, colors

Every time I print in Chrome 13, I have to click Color because it defaults to black and white.

Does anyone else have this problem?

Does anyone have a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved now. (Chrome 14) They fixed the issue with certain printouts including a second page which was blank. They also fixed the default to be color instead of black and white.

Comment: I am using Chrome 14 but it still defaults to B&W. Can't tell you how much paper and ink I've wasted because of this.

Comment: I noticed, I think it is a bit unsure, but for me, I think it takes what is last used, perhaps on a per site basis, don't know, have not studied it much. I just noticed that I hardly need to set it to color anymore. (which I used to do every time)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a chrome issue, it is the printer default setting. Just change the default (control panel -> printers -> device settings).

Comment: See screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/OsfuK.jpg. There is no option for Color/B&W. Perhaps since there is no option, that is why Chrome is not defaulting correctly. Do you think so?